# Bootloading ATmega 328P-PU "target does'nt answer"

Tags: arduino, avr, bootloader, atmega

I have fiddled with this for a cupple of days now.

Im bootloading a 328p with a now updated USBasp.

I got a new 328p from a new Arduino UNO which i can't bootload. Keeps giving me the:

```
avrdude: error: programm enable: target doesn't answer. 1 
avrdude: initialization failed, rc=-1
     Double check connections and try again, or use -F to override
     this check.
```

The old 328p from ebay which now is dead had no problems getting bootloaded!

And yes. i checked my connections and measured them out 10 times. I also updated the firmware on my USBasp.

Is the 328p from the arduino locked in some sort of way? Any ideas on this one?

Full output:

```
avrdude: Version 6.0.1, compiled on Apr 14 2015 at 16:30:25
     Copyright (c) 2000-2005 Brian Dean, http://www.bdmicro.com/
     Copyright (c) 2007-2009 Joerg Wunsch

     System wide configuration file is "/Applications/Arduino.app/Contents/Java/hardware/tools/avr/etc/avrdude.conf"
     User configuration file is "/Users/madsgadebergjensen/.avrduderc"
     User configuration file does not exist or is not a regular file, skipping

     Using Port                    : usb
     Using Programmer              : usbasp
     AVR Part                      : ATmega328P
     Chip Erase delay              : 9000 us
     PAGEL                         : PD7
     BS2                           : PC2
     RESET disposition             : dedicated
     RETRY pulse                   : SCK
     serial program mode           : yes
     parallel program mode         : yes
     Timeout                       : 200
     StabDelay                     : 100
     CmdexeDelay                   : 25
     SyncLoops                     : 32
     ByteDelay                     : 0
     PollIndex                     : 3
     PollValue                     : 0x53
     Memory Detail                 :

                              Block Poll               Page                       Polled
       Memory Type Mode Delay Size  Indx Paged  Size   Size #Pages MinW  MaxW   ReadBack
       ----------- ---- ----- ----- ---- ------ ------ ---- ------ ----- ----- ---------
       eeprom        65    20     4    0 no       1024    4      0  3600  3600 0xff 0xff
       flash         65     6   128    0 yes     32768  128    256  4500  4500 0xff 0xff
       lfuse          0     0     0    0 no          1    0      0  4500  4500 0x00 0x00
       hfuse          0     0     0    0 no          1    0      0  4500  4500 0x00 0x00
       efuse          0     0     0    0 no          1    0      0  4500  4500 0x00 0x00
       lock           0     0     0    0 no          1    0      0  4500  4500 0x00 0x00
       calibration    0     0     0    0 no          1    0      0     0     0 0x00 0x00
       signature      0     0     0    0 no          3    0      0     0     0 0x00 0x00

     Programmer Type : usbasp
     Description     : USBasp, http://www.fischl.de/usbasp/
```

avrdude: auto set sck period (because given equals null)
avrdude: error: programm enable: target doesn't answer. 1 
avrdude: initialization failed, rc=-1
         Double check connections and try again, or use -F to override
         this check.

avrdude done.  Thank you.

Error while burning bootloader.

Answer (score 1):

Have you try to use the avrdude program from command line?

Locate your avrdude.exe, normally:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Arduino\hardware\tools\avr\bin\
```

Go to this folder (CMD) and you must see the avrdude.exe file.

Type this:

```
avrdude.exe -C"C:\Program Files (x86)\Arduino\hardware/tools/avr/etc/avrdude.conf" 
-v -pm328p -cusbasp -U lfuse:w:0xE2:m -U hfuse:w:0xD9:m -U efuse:w:0x07:m
```

Explanation:

```
-v: Verbose mode.
-pm328p: Chip model.
-cusbasp: Programmer
Set fuses, in the example LFUSE:E2 HFUSE:D9 EFUSE:07.
```

You can check and calculate new fuses here:
http://www.engbedded.com/fusecalc/

Hope this solve your problem.

Best regards